# need to get the id of a selected spinner value from sqlite in android

Tags: android

I Need to get the id of a selected spinner value from sqlite database in android

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {        
        String label = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();        
        Log.d("label:", label); 
}
```

I need to return the id of the id of the selected value

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
int getId(String label)
{
SqliteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cur=db.rawQuery("SELECT ID FROM TABLENAME WHERE NAME=\""+label+"\"");
cur.moveToFirst();
String ID=cur.getString(0);
return Integer.valueOf(ID);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your MAin activity try this code for your spinner

```
    spin_category.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
    {
       public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) 
       {
          category_id=arg2;
          int my_id=db.getID(category_id);
       }
       public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) 
       {
       }
   });
```

In You Database class write this function

```
public int getID(int id) 
{
   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
   Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_NAME}, KEY_ID+"=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null);
   if(cursor!=null)
   if (cursor.getCount() > 0) 
   {
     cursor.moveToFirst();
   }
   int s = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID));
   cursor.close();    
   db.close();
   return s;
}
```

The first function will get id of selected item in spinner and will pass it to database method and second function will search for that id and return id of that id. As I am not very clear with your requirement. Please comment if you want it in different way.

Answer (score 0):

If your adapter is a SimpleCursorAdapter, you already have the id of the selected one provided by the parameter 'id'. If it is a custom adapter, override the adapter's getItemId() method to return the correct id for a selected row.

You don't really need to do this either:

```
String label = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
```

...since the parameter 'view' already provides the selected item within the parent, i.e. you can do this instead:

```
String label = view.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {        
        String label = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();        
        Log.d("label:", label); 
}


spinner_referrer_to_type.getSelectedItem().toString();
```